# MySQL: user-variable definition within SQL statement to create counter column

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, mariadb

Is it possible to create a counter in mysql/mariadb in one single SELECT-statement. I've tried the following but it returns only the value 1 in the first column:

```
SELECT @rownr := IF(ISNULL(@rownr),0,@rownr)+1 AS rowNumber, * FROM table_x LIMIT 0,10
```

If I run the statement more often in the same mysql-instance it starts counting from the last number. So the second time it starts at 2, the third time at 12. This means that the variable is created but seems to be only available for modification when it was instantiated before the SQL statement was issued.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but a bit tricky. First, you need to declare the variable outside of the `select` clause (in a separate `set` assignment, or in a derived table). Also, it is safer to sort the rows in a subquery first, and then compute the variable.

I would recommend:

```
set @rn := 0;
select t.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rowNumber
from (select t.* from mytable t order by id limit 10) t
```

Note that I added an `order by` clause to the inner query, otherwise it is undefined in which sequence rows will be ordered (I assumed `id`).

Alternatively, you can declare the variable in a derived table:

```
select t.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rowNumber
from (select t.* from mytable t order by id limit 10) t
cross join (select @rn := 0) x
```

Finally: if you are running MySQL 8.0, just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn 
from mytable t
order by id
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `order by`, so the ordering is indeterminate.  But you can initialize the parameter in the statement itself:

```
SELECT @rownr := (@rownr + 1) AS rowNumber, x.*
FROM table_x x.CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rownr := 0) params
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

If you want a particular ordering, you should use an `order by` in a subquery.

Also note that starting in MySQL 8, variable assignments in `SELECT` are deprecated.  You should be using window functions (`row_number()`) in more recent versions.

Comment: Thx GMB and Gordon, this gives enough food for solutions. In my enviroment I cannot issue 2 sql-statements squentially in the same action so the 1st alternative is no option.  I had not thought about the CROSS JOIN option where the linked table is evaluated first so the variable is instantiated before it is evaluated by the outer SELECT statement.